# Why do I get a blank screen appearing before video has started playing in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am developing an `android` app. The app contains an `activity` that will show `videos` which are present on my `server`. (I have written code for this and it is working fine).

When I click on `video` play button it shows a full blank screen and then after a few seconds the `video` plays.

How do I avoid this blank screen and directly play the `video`.?

Comment: I think it will try to run from server, Not locally.

Comment: You haven't shared any code. are you using `VideoView`?

Comment: yes i am using video view